# AWS ElasticBeanstalk, CodeDeploy vs Capistrano, Mina, Vlad, etc

Tags: amazon-web-services, capistrano, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

Trying to host my PHP project on an AWS auto scaling group, and wanted to have a fast deployer and server automation tool.

Was using Capistrano for other projects and found it fairly good. The only problem was I didn't figure out the best way to use Capistrano to deploy on an auto scaling group in AWS.

Then I tried ElasticBeanstalk and CodeDeploy as they natively support auto scaling, but it seems that we would have to archive/bundle the app (upload/commit the bundle to S3/GitHub) each time we wanted to deploy. And also we would need to include those **vendor** files in the bundle even though they were already put into the EC2 instances by previous deployments. This makes each deployment terribly slow.

I'm new to these 2 AWS services, there could be something I did wrong. Wondering **if there is some service in AWS which deploys in a similar way as Heroku does** (instead of bundling the whole app, just pulling the latest changes from GitHub)?

Or if we use tools like Capistrano, **is there a proper way to handle auto scaling?**

Answer (score 0):

Using CodeDeploy, you can trigger an automatic deployment from a GitHub repository whenever the source code changes. For additional information, checkout this blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automatically-deploy-from-github-using-aws-codedeploy/